# react-draft-wysiwyg - Warning: Can't call setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate, strict-mode, draft-js-plugins, react-draft-wysiwyg

I did make a simple react app with react-draft-wysiwyg, but I get a warning.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import "../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Editor />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When I click on the editor iget this error in the console, but only when I run it in StrictMode:

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the r component.

I did make a codeSandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-monad-lxtuu?file=/src/index.js:0-295
Try click at the editor and look at the warnings in the console.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Looking through the docs you need more dependencies in order to use it https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which dependencies? 
Try look at example number 7 (Editor i18n - korean locale). It dosnt have more dependencies?

Comment: Even if I use the basic example at https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/master/stories/Basic/index.js I get the same warning if I run it in React.StrictMode.

Comment: was a solution found @AlexanderJuhl

Comment: No sorry, no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package has some problem with StrictMode.
Just remove StrictMode:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import "../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Editor />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: No strictmode is not an option. I think the package is broken then.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderJuhl don't use this package until it is updated, I'm using it right now, so I might go and take a look.

Comment: Look over github. the package has a fix but it is not yet merged.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code, it should work

```
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg' 
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js'

const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty())
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
setIsMounted(true)
   return () => {
    setIsMounted(false)
}
}, [])

<div  className="order_detail">
    {isMounted && (
        <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            wrapperClassName="editor"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
        />
    )}
</div>
```